# Algebraic Description of Diagonal Divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Consider a elliptically fibered variety $\pi: X\rightarrow B$ (with fiber $E$), and suppose we construct the fiber product $X\times_B X$. Then naturally there is a diagonal divisor $\Delta$ (which is Weil if I'm right), over each point $p\in B$ it reduces to the diagonal of $E\times E$. Because it's Weil, it's not possible to find a global algebraic description of $\Delta$.

**Question1** : I just want to make sure what I just said is true. (probably it's wrong, and it's actually Cartier...)

**Question2** : How to compute intersection numbers which involve $\Delta$, I know for example it's possible to compute self intersection by using GRR for $\delta: X \rightarrow X\times_B X$. But in other cases I don't know any clear/practical way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: For a Weil divisor, there is no reasonable concept of intersection with another (or the same) Weil divisor.

Comment: I see. But for $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartiers its make sense? So how it's possible to check that?...

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier implies some integer multiple is Cartier and intersection with Cartier divisors make sense. So, if $n\Delta$ is Cartier, then $\Delta\cdot C$ for a curve $C$ is just $\frac{1}{n}(n\Delta\cdot C)$.